# Undefined Property in object when using typescript

Tags: typescript, async-await, typeorm

I want to bring each property of the object as a result of executing the query.

**UserBody**

```
export interface UserBody {
  empno: string;
  password: string;
  class?: string;
  user_id?: string;
  deptcd?: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

**auth.ts**

```
const result: UserBody[] = await getManager(body.store_code).query(`${query}`) as UserBody[]
```

And then, get a property from result object, but it shows undefined when use console.log
like,

```
console.log(result[0].empno)
```

I specified a type for each property in the type UserBody, but I don't understand why the object property is undefined.

---

++Edit

In result, the return value is declared UserBody[], and getManager().In the case of query(), it says Promise.

```
result => return type: UserBody[]

getManager().query => return type: Promise<any>
```

I think the reason why it is output as undefined is because the type is not specified.
Promise is the return value, and it should be assigned to the construct, which I thought could specify the type of component through construct: UserBody[ ].

I'm going to compare the passwords received through communication with the passwords of the database.

But getManager().query() The password return value (which is result) appears undefined.

Please point out if there is anything wrong with the setting.

Comment: well youve as asserted the type. what does it say if you dont have the assertion?

Comment: @lockednlevered I'm not used to using typescript. is any way to assert the type?

Comment: please provide the code of getManager

Comment: The type assertion just tells the compiler that the type should be this other type, it does not actually convert the value. You still need to check that result[0] is not undefined.https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion

Comment: @Jerome I just called getManager from typeorm.
import { getManager } from 'typeorm'

Comment: @lockednlevered you mean if i want a empno from result[0], let empno = <string>result[0].empno ? but it return undefined

Comment: Please provide reproducible example

Comment: I solved my problem. Unbelievably, it was a upper-lower case problem. Thank you to those who answered.